# Launch one application from another application and state of application launched should be maintained in android

Tags: android, launch

I want to launch one application from another application in android.

Say in App1:

- I am in Activity1
- Then Activity2
- Then Activity3

From App2 I launch App1.

- Directly Activity3 of App1 should be display and not Activity1

I tried with following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager(); 
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.emailDemo");     i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.emailDemo", "com.android.emailDemo.EmailAppDemo")); 
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(i);
```

Can any one please help?

Comment: Have you tried it? How does it work when you tried?

Comment: Yes. I have tried using following code. But it display main launch activity.

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();    
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.emailDemo");
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.emailDemo", "com.android.emailDemo.EmailAppDemo"));
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Android can do that through Manifest flags and launch modes. Each activity can have a set of flags to instruct the system how intents can be managed to them. I believe you'd have to send the action which your Activity3 is responsible for and set flags so no other task is created.

Read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Try setting your activity launch mode to "single-top" http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Its just an example that it is currently in Activity3. It may be in Activity2 or Activity4. Last state of that application (Activity2/Activity4) should be maintained and not Activity1.